# symbolicatecrash does not give me method names for my own functions

Tags: iphone, debugging, symbols, debug-symbols, symbolicate

Running into a weird issue using symbolicatecrash to debug crash logs. After I run symbolicatecrash with the .dSYM file of the build that crashed, it gives me function names for all of the Foundation classes, but not for my own app. Is there some setting in XCode that I may be missing? GENERATE DEBUG SYMBOLS is turned on to YES.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which turned out to be caused by a bug in the `symbolicatecrash` script and **the app name containing a period "."** (e.g. *my.new.app*). This bug has been reported to Apple (rdar://[8352458](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=646403)) and apparently can be solved with the following patch:

```
  214c214
  <     $executable =~ s/\..*//g;         # strip off the suffix, if any
  ---
  >     $executable =~ s/\.[^\.]*$//g;    # strip off the suffix, if any
```

The `symbolicatecrash` script file can usually be found at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/symbolicatecrash`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. Try [this](http://code.coneybeare.net/fixing-symbolicatecrash). If it doesn't exactly fix your issue, it will send you in the right direction.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I seem to be getting the opposite problem that most people are having. My own code isn't getting symbolicated, but Apple's code is!